# Get the courses taught by a teacher which average score is above a value

Tags: sql, relational-database

Here are 2 tables and their relations. A teacher may teach more than one course. The relation between Course and Course_Score is 1:n. The students' scores are stored in course_score.

Course(*cid*, tid*) [1 ------n] Course_Score(*cid**, *sid**, score)

*Italic* attributes are primary keys. The attribute marked with * is the foreign key. Like, *sid** is a student ID. *tid** is a teacher ID.

How to get the teacher's ID that the courses taught by this teacher have an average score all above 80?

I tried below but it didn't work because it returned more data than it should return.

> SELECT tid FROM course WHERE EXISTS
>    (SELECT avg(score) FROM course_score NATURAL JOIN course
>    GROUP BY cid HAVING avg(score) > 80);

Comment: what does "didn't work" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to reformulate this question as "show me teachers that don't have a course with an average score of 80 or under":

```
select
    tid
from
    teacher t
where
    not exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            course_score cs
                inner join
            course c
                on cs.cid = c.cid
        where
            c.tid = t.tid
        group by
            c.cid
        having
            avg(score) <= 80
    );
```

There may be some argument as to whether teachers that have taught zero courses should be included or not.

[Here's an example to show it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbe1e/1)

One thing to watch out for is that calculating averages of an int field can be tricky, as the answer may get rounded to an int. Change it to `avg(cast (score as decimal))` to fix this.

Comment: Isn't that going to be a *Relational Division* to give the correct answer in all cases? That's got to be more complex than correcting what OP already has.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Even with your fix, OP is picking teachers that have taught at least one course with an average over 80. The question asks for teachers where all their courses have an average over 80.

Comment: This returns zero record. There may have a problem somewhere.

Comment: @canoe post some test data.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting your *tid* values from *courses*; of course you are getting too many rows.

<s>Instead, change the top of your query to this:</s>

```
SELECT tid FROM teacher
```

**Update** Just saw that *"all above"** in the spec.

```
SELECT teacher.tid 
FROM teacher 
JOIN (
    SELECT tid,cid, avg(score) as avg_score
    FROM course_score
    JOIN course on course.cid = course_score.cid
    GROUP BY tid,cid
)scores
 on scores.tid = teacher.tid
GROUP BY teacher.tid
HAVING min(avg_score) > 80
```

Comment: You are using another cool solution! But the subquery `SELECT tid,cid, avg(score) as avg_score FROM course_score` probably won't work as tid isn't in table course_score.